# HTML table horizontal spacing

Tags: html, html-table, cells, spacing

How can I set an X spacing between html table's columns?

Using cellpadding or cellspacing I got vertical spacing too (and I don't want it!).

I can't use CSS. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, how about inserting an extra column with width=X ? I think it is the only way to do that in pure html.

Comment: be aware that some renderes are weird when it comes to empty columns, so you may have to insert something for it to appear.

Comment: you have to insert at least a