# Append html space algorithm

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

This question is along the lines of [HTML table horizontal spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371088/html-table-horizontal-spacing)

We have an old code base and can not use css.  When an entire column in a table is empty, the resulting table is very ugly.  We have a text email solution that adds spaces to the end up a word up to the remaining set of characters that you specify using New String.  Since New String only takes a char, was seeing what 1 liner, small amount of code examples people could come up with.

We use .net 3.5sp1

```
Public Function StringSize(ByVal data As String, ByVal size As Short, ByVal usehtml As Boolean) As String
    If data.Length > size Then
        Return Left(data, size - 4) & "... "
    Else
        If usehtml Then
            'small algorithm here ( & nbsp ; )
        Else
            Return data & New String(" ", size - Len(data))
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can use .NET 3.5 SP1 but you can't use CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ***really*** want to pad with `&nbsp;`, then - well, frankly - I'm not sure it is a great idea, but something like (excuse the C#):

```
int count = size - data.Length;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
    data, data.Length + (6 * count));
for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    sb.Append("&nbsp;");
}
string s = sb.ToString();
```

The following is a **bad** way to do it in one line with LINQ; included only for interest:

```
string s = data + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", size - data.Length).ToArray());
```

Comment: I assume the downvote is for using C#... that is just petty; the translation is absolutely trivial for someone familiar with VB... I maintain that an answer in VB is fine for most "C#" questions, and an answer in C# is fine for most "VB" questions - as most of the time, the question is really about the framework, not the language. Obviously for *language* specifics it would matter. But this isn't a language question.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use a StringBuilder and a For loop.

```
Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
For i = 1 To size - Len(data)
    ' Be sure to take out the space in the nbsp, Stack Overflow doesn't like it for some reason.
    builder.Append("& nbsp;")
Next
Return builder.ToString()
```